Laravel Make:Command returning Content-type: text/html
I am running the following command to create a new command in my Laravel website;
php artisan make:command CheckPendingOrders

However when I run this, I get the below response:
Content-type: text/html

I'm using Putty to write the commands, and I have targeted the command at the route folder for this site.
I expected the command to create a new command in App\Console\Commands, however it didn't do this.

You're going to have to dig through the other commands, and possibly other files, to find out where this is coming from. When you run one command, it actually initializes all of the other commands, which will trigger any code in their __construct() functions.

Thanks, I found the solution. I needed to add the version of PHP next to the php command. So for mine it worked out to be php8.3 etc.....
